# Im getting the output as [10,10] but dont know the reason why so

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```
l = [10,10,10,10]

for x in l:
    l.remove(x)

print(l)
```

Im getting the output as [10,10]

But not able to understand why

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please also format your question correctly to display your code in a code block.

Comment: You're iterating over a list and modifying it. You're skipping every second index.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for i,e in enumerate(l):
    l.remove(e)
    print(i)

print(l)
```

Output: [2, 4]

First iteration, frst element is removing, then the list is [2, 3, 4].
Second iteration, you remove the second element of the new list ([2, 3, 4]), so you remove the 3, and 4 become the 2nd element.
After that, you can't remove the third element because it does'nt exist.

If you run my code, you'll see that only 2 iterations are done.

If you want to delete items without modify index of the next, you can start by the end of the list as above.

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for i in range(len(l) - 1, - 1, -1):
    l.remove(l[i])
    print(i)

print(l)
```

This time the loop is running 4 times and the final list is empty.